# unable to replace white spaces with dash in python using string.replace(" ", "_")

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df).drop(["Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1"], axis=1)
df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)
names = df["Coin"].str.rsplit(n=2).str[0].str.lower()
coins=names.replace(" ", "-")
print(coins)
```

The print is still printing coins with spaces in their names. I want to replace the spaces with dashes (-). Can someone please help

Comment: `df['coin'].str.replace(" ", "-")` will work. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: Can you please share the example output and the expected results also

Comment: Try `coins=names.str.replace(" ", "-")` But Alok is right, instead of showing your whole snippet, you should give us the value of `names` (or a portion of it). This helps narrow down the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a parameter `regex=True` to make it work:

```
coins = names.replace(" ", "-", regex=True)
```

The reason is that for [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) function, it looks for ***exact match***  when replacing strings without `regex=True` (default is `regex=False`):

[Official doc:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

> **str**: string **exactly matching** *to_replace* will be replaced with value
>
> **regex**: regexs matching *to_replace* will be replaced with value

Therefore, unless your strings to replace contains only exactly one space (no other characters), there will be no match for the string to replace.  Hence, no result with the code without `regex=True`.

---

Alternatively, you can also use [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) instead of [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
coins = names.str.replace(" ", "-")
```

`.str.replace()` **does not require exact match** and matches for partial string regardless of whether `regex=True` or `regex=False`.

**Result:**

```
print(coins)


0                              safebreastinu
1     unicly-bored-ape-yacht-club-collection
2                                 bundle-dao
3                                   shibamax
4                                      swapp
                       ...                  
95                        apollo-space-token
96                  futurov-governance-token
97                              safemoon-inu
98                                         x
99                           black-kishu-inu
Name: Coin, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

Comment: Would you also know why `regex=True` only works in this case?

Comment: Pandas is a bit confusing in this area as per my observation.  Sometimes we need a raw-string to quote the strings.  Sometimes, the substitute part doesn't need.  I think internally, Pandas made some assumption of the nature of characters.

Comment: @Ank See my edit above which explains why `regex=True` makes it work.